# Server Error in '/' Application. Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to develop a C# web-based system with multiple user roles. Created in my project is sub-folders for Human Resources (HR), Finance and Contractors. In addition I am inheriting from the MaterPage which is in the root folder. This uses siteMaps. However, I am encountering this error when I try to access the folders. I have looked at the other examples and changed my code to use ~/ but still having the same error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
________________________________________
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 

[HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.]
   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.ReduceVirtualPath(String path) +12066575
   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Reduce(String path) +60
   System.Web.UI.Control.ResolveClientUrl(String relativeUrl) +258
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink.RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer) +91
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +65
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +79
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +250
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +27
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +47
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +79
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +250
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +79
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +250
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +39
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +79
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8753
```

HR Webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <allow roles="HR"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Webconfig:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=KANY-WEST\MSSQLSERVERKANY;Initial Catalog=OfficeSolutions;Integrated Security=True"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <siteMap enabled ="true" defaultProvider="SiteMap">
          <providers>
            <add name="SiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
          </providers>
        </siteMap>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

SiteMap:

```
SiteMap:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="" title="Home" description="" roles ="*">
    <siteMapNode url="~/Home.aspx" title="Home" description="Home Page"  roles="*" />
    <siteMapNode url="javascript:;" title="Admin" description="Admin Page" roles ="Administrator">
      <siteMapNode url ="~/Admin/Users.aspx" title="Users" description="Users Page"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url ="~/Admin/Reports.aspx" title="Reports" description="Reports Page"></siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
       <siteMapNode url="~/Contact.aspx" title="Contact" description="Contact Us Page"  roles="*" />
       <siteMapNode url="~/ViewMessages.aspx" title="Dash Board" description="Message Dash Board"  roles="*" />
       <siteMapNode url="~/CreateNewMessage.aspx" title="New Message" description="Create New Message"  roles="*" />
       <siteMapNode url="~/HR/HR.aspx" title="HR" description="HR"  roles="HR" />
       <siteMapNode url="~/Finance/Finance.aspx" title="Finance" description="Finance"  roles="Finance" />
       <siteMapNode url="~/Contractors/Contractors.aspx" title="Contractors" description="Contractors"  roles="Contractors" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

HR.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HR.aspx.cs" Inherits="MessagingSolutions.HR.HR" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<h1>HR Files</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

## HR Files

Comment: I'd suggest searching your codebase for `..`.

Comment: Based from the stack trace, you have `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink` throwing exception because of `..\ ` or `~/` in path usage (the page itself is already in root level). Try provide detailed markup from page which causing error.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto my Page inherits from the Master Page. However, the Markup is as follows:

Comment: Try removing tilde in page definition so that your master page becomes `MasterPageFile="MasterPage.Master"`. Can you provide site folder hierarchy to make sure that master page linked well?

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of the Bootstrap in the Master was wrong. I removed this and it worked by just placing it further down the CSS.